# How can I serve multiple rails apps on single VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a VPS on digital ocean. I can able to run multiple rails apps on same VPS using nginx+passenger. Now i want to map domain names. For this what should I do?

**My nginx.conf file**

```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ~ ^/uvarsity(/.*|$) {
        alias /home/uvarsity/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
        passenger_base_uri /uvarsity;
        passenger_app_root /home/uvarsity;
        passenger_document_root /home/uvarsity/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }
   location ~ ^/uvarsity-landing(/.*|$) {
        alias /home/uvarsity-lp/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
        passenger_base_uri /uvarsity-landing;
        passenger_app_root /home/uvarsity-lp;
        passenger_document_root /home/uvarsity-lp/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }
 location / {
      root /home/amaravati/public;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "map domain names"?

Comment: map domain names means i want to point domain names to these rails apps @DanFarrell

Comment: do u have more than 1 domain name ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is virtual hosting.

The trick here is to define an `upstream` section in NGINX to define each application's backend server(s), and then a `server` section that passes traffic to the upstream.

Here's a very simple example I used to provide a virtual host `localhost` that redirected to a virtual machine running on VirtualBox.  I was using `localhost` but the only requirement is that your browser requests the host by the name matching the `server_name` setting in the `server` block in the `nginx` config.

```
upstream apache {
        server 192.168.70.1:1025;
}

server {
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://apache;
        }

}
```

Comment: Now is this fix my problem                                           upstream apache {
        server ip;
}

Comment: Upstream is used for load balancing. is it useful here also @DanFarrell

Comment: The real trick here is using `proxy_pass` to point to a backend server.  You're right - an `upstream` block really isn't required for one backend.  You could just say `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567` or whatever the ralis app is listening on.